# XSLT: flat XML to nested hierarchy based on path

Tags: xslt, hierarchy, siblings

I am trying to create a nested hierarchy from flat XML based on `level` elements that represent a path. Each `level` element and its belonging siblings (names and number vary) should be wrapped in a 'record' element thus creating a tree structure.

From this **source** (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     
<record>     
    <level>first</level>     
    <unitid>0001</unitid>
    <a-few-more-siblings/>     
    <level>first/second</level>     
    <unitid>0002</unitid>     
    <many-more-siblings/>
    <level>first/second/third</level>     
    <unitid>0003a</unitid>
    <some-more-siblings/>     
    <level>first/second/third</level>
     <unitid>0003b</unitid>
    <many-more-siblings/>
    <level>first/second/third</level>     
    <unitid>0003c</unitid>
    <some-more-siblings/>  
    <level>first</level>     
    <unitid>0004</unitid> 
    <again-more-siblings/>      
</record>
```

I would like to generate the following **desired output**:

```
<Record level="first"> 
    <level>first</level>
    <unitid>001</unitid>
    <a-few-more-siblings/>
    <Record level="second"> 
        <level>second</level>
        <unitid>002</unitid>
        <many-more-siblings/>
        <Record level="third">
            <level>third</level>
            <unitid>003a</unitid>
            <some-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
        <Record level="third"> 
            <level>third</level>
            <unitid>003b</unitid>
            <many-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
        <Record level="third"> 
            <level>third</level>
            <unitid>003c</unitid>
            <some-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
    </Record>    
</Record>
<Record level="first">
    <level>first</level>
    <unitid>0004</unitid>
    <again-more-siblings/>
</Record>
```

The closest I could produce so far is:

```
<record level="first">
   <level>first</level>
   <unitid>0001</unitid>
   <some-other-siblings/>
   <record level="second">
      <level>first/second</level>
      <unitid>0002</unitid>
      <some-other-siblings/>
      <record level="third">
             <level>first/second</level>
             <unitid>0002</unitid>
             <some-other-siblings/>
         <level>first/second/third</level>
         <unitid>0003a</unitid>
         <some-other-siblings/>
      </record>
      <record level="third">
             <level>first/second</level>
             <unitid>0002</unitid>
             <some-other-siblings/>
             <level>first/second/third</level>
             <unitid>0003a</unitid>
             <some-other-siblings/>
         <level>first/second/third</level>
         <unitid>0003b</unitid>
         <some-other-siblings/>
      </record>
      <record level="third">
         <level>first/second/third</level>
         <unitid>0003c</unitid>
         <some-other-siblings/>
      </Record>
   </record>
</record>
```

(undesirable siblings on third level additionally indented; `0004` on first level fails to appear)

I tried different variations of approaches suggested to similar problems ("flat to hierarchical", "following siblings until", etc.), but end up either stuck with too many siblings printed at a certain position or with the output of only the first record on the third level.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this could be to make use of keys. For a start to get the siblings of a `level` element you could define a key to group elements by the first most preceding `level` element (i.e the group will be all the siblings).

```
<xsl:key name="siblings" 
     match="*[not(self::level)]" 
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::level[1])" />
```

You could also define a key to get the immediate 'descendant' of a `level` element (i.e for each level, group them by the first most preceding level with a short name).

```
<xsl:key name="nextlevel" 
     match="level" 
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::level[starts-with(current(), concat(., '/'))][1])" />
```

In your XSLT you would then start of simply by selecting the 'first' level elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="level[. = 'first']" />
```

You would then have a generic template matching `level` elements where you could utilise both the keys to output the siblings and the next level elements

```
<xsl:template match="level">
    <Record level="{.}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('siblings', generate-id())" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nextlevel', generate-id())" />
    </Record>
</xsl:template>
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="siblings" match="*[not(self::level)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::level[1])" />

    <xsl:key name="nextlevel" match="level" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::level[starts-with(current(), concat(., '/'))][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="level[. = 'first']" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level">
        <Record level="{.}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('siblings', generate-id())" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nextlevel', generate-id())" />
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Record level="first">
    <level>first</level>
    <unitid>0001</unitid>
    <a-few-more-siblings/>
    <Record level="first/second">
        <level>first/second</level>
        <unitid>0002</unitid>
        <many-more-siblings/>
        <Record level="first/second/third">
            <level>first/second/third</level>
            <unitid>0003a</unitid>
            <some-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
        <Record level="first/second/third">
            <level>first/second/third</level>
            <unitid>0003b</unitid>
            <many-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
        <Record level="first/second/third">
            <level>first/second/third</level>
            <unitid>0003c</unitid>
            <some-more-siblings/>
        </Record>
    </Record>
</Record>
<Record level="first">
    <level>first</level>
    <unitid>0004</unitid>
    <again-more-siblings/>
</Record>
```

This isn't quite what you are currently showing as your expected output, because your expected output has two 'first' `level` elements wrapped in a single `Record` element (compared with separate `Record` elements for the 'third' `level` elements). If your expected output is really what you expect, try replacing the template that matches `record` with these two templates instead:

```
<xsl:template match="record">
    <Record level="first">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="level[. = 'first']" />
     </Record>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level[. = 'first']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('siblings', generate-id())" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nextlevel', generate-id())" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. And a very good observation regarding the `first` level elements. Indeed I had added the second one later in order to illustrate that following siblings may belong to higher levels, but got confused myself.